# Cannot browse App documents after upgrading to iOS 8.3

Tags: applications, ios, file

I just upgraded my iPhone 5s to iOS 8.3. I found that I am unable to access the contents of Apps using software like iTools, iFunbox and PhoneView.

Does iOS 8.3 change security settings in App document folders?

Tried software:

1. iFunbox
2. iTools (latest version & version 2013)
3. PhoneView (demo version)
4. iMazing (trial version)
5. iExplorer (trial version)

---

**UPDATE** Here is the [security content change log of iOS 8.3](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204661) regarding the document access (CVE-2015-1087):

> **Backup**
>
> Available for: iPhone 4s and later, iPod touch (5th generation)
>   and later, iPad 2 and later Impact: An attacker may be able to use the
>   backup system to access restricted areas of the file system
>   Description: An issue existed in the relative path evaluation logic of
>   the backup system. This issues was addressed through improved path
>   evaluation.
>
> CVE-ID
>
> CVE-2015-1087 : TaiG Jailbreak Team

Comment: I know there was an update for iExplorer to support 8.3. I'm assuming other apps will require updates as well.

Comment: yes, related articles [here](http://iexplorer-support.macroplant.com/customer/portal/articles/1942869)

Comment: I've raised a stackoverflow question, as I develop an app that is experiencing this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29556944/idevice-connecttoservice-on-ios-8-3. Interestingly, I've noticed that this only occurs on apps installed from the app store. Enterprise apps seem to work fine.

Comment: iExplorer's newest update does not help to browse app documents. it seems like we need to wait for the developers of these application browsers to be aware that they don't work on ios 8.3 anymore.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Macrumors](http://www.macrumors.com/2015/04/13/ios-8-3-ifunbox-itools-sandbox-app-access/):

"Apple has changed security settings in iOS 8.3 that prevent file managers and transfer utilities such as iFunBox, iTools, iExplorer, iBackupBot and PhoneView from gaining access to app directories on an iPhone, iPad or iPod touch.

The change breaks current versions of transfer utilities for OS X and Windows, forcing many developers to release new versions of their software with workarounds that restore at least partial sandbox access."